# Is there something fike %MOZILLAROOT% in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, mozilla

Is there a possibility to use in Mozilla's homepage settings a constant, something like this: %MOZILLAROOT% by analogy with %SYSTEMROOT%?

```
For example: %MOZILLAROOT%/profile/index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

2 paths:

- `which firefox` to return the Firefox installation path (`/usr/bin/firefox`).
- Your profile in `~/.firefox/profile/`

Comment: May be, you did not understand the question.
I need to specify relative path in portable installation of FF.
So I want to know, does FF have internal command, that gives the root folder, which could be used in relative path to homepage.

Comment: Is there in FF something like "firefox_root", that can be used as:
file:///firefox_root/homepage.html ???

Comment: First of all, you did not say you have a **portable** version of Firefox, and you must edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Secondly, I do not think there is such thing in Firefox, although I would try with the usual relative paths like "./foo.html" and check how it reacts, even if you can not in the settings, should try with the program variables in `about:config`.

Comment: I do not see no difference between portable and non-portable versions.
The program should know it's root folder, and it does.
In about:config there is a variable "browser.open.dir" it shows the way I need. But how could I use this variable in address in homepage's settings?
Records like "file:///index.html" or "file:///browser.open.dir/index.html" open just an empty silver window. No alerts, no mistakes.

Comment: Well, the main difference is not in the program itself (usually, depends of the program obviously), but how "installed" is in the computer. For example, if you have it installed in a well-known path, you can just link it with the command I said like `firefox $(which firefox)/webpage.html`, that will always open the file "webpage.html" in the system it is installed for example.

Comment: Although, something harder, but also possible to do: Firefox is open source and also very customizable, so it is possible to change the startup webpage to let you customize its default one or just replace it.
Another possibility, is to set up your own web server, and place your server's public IP/domain as the default webpage.

Comment: I just wanted to set somehow the local homepage in FF settings relative to the program folder. Because the root disk can change.
Now I see that it is probably impossible...
Pity.

Comment: Sorry, for now it seems to not be possible to be done as you would like (if there is, please someone answer), but maybe there are more ways to do it like I said.
Also, at this point you could tell us what you pretended if you do not mind, maybe we could help you with another solution.